# Can we get a <title> for the Hat Dash leaderboard?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

The [Hat Dash leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/leaderboard) currently has a blank `<title></title>` tag.

Can the page get a title, e.g. `<title>Hat Dash Leaderboard - Winter Bash</title>`, like the other pages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Hat Dash leaderboard now has a title

> it's hard to refer
> to a page when title-less
> hope now tabs all fine